# Binding an Obj-C type implementing the NSFastEnumeration protocol to MonoTouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to write a MonoTouch binding for the ZBar library and have got stuck on the `ZBarSymbolSet` type. It looks pretty simple at first glance:

```
@interface ZBarSymbolSet
    : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
{
    const zbar_symbol_set_t *set;
    BOOL filterSymbols;
}

@property (readonly, nonatomic) int count;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) const zbar_symbol_set_t *zbarSymbolSet;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL filterSymbols;

- (id) initWithSymbolSet: (const zbar_symbol_set_t*) set;

@end


@interface ZBarSymbol : NSObject
... I've left out the ZBarSymbol members, all thats important is that the ZBarSymbolSet should be an IEnumerable<ZBarSymbol>
@end
```

But the problems began when I started looking into how to bind the standard .NET `IEnumerable` interface to the `NSFastEnumerator` protocol implementation. I have no idea really where to even start with this.

Answer (score 2):

So I didn't find an automatic way to instruct btouch to hook up the `NSFastEnumerable` protocol methods to provide an `IEnumerable` interface implementation on the binding class. Instead I took the manual approach, and added my own partial class with IEnumerable implementation. Within this I then had to actually call direct into the C library that this Obj-C library was wrapping!

```
public partial class ZBarSymbolSet : IEnumerable<ZBarSymbol>
{
    public IEnumerator<ZBarSymbol> GetEnumerator ()
    {
        IntPtr symbol;
        if ( FilterEnabled )
            symbol = zbar_symbol_set_first_symbol(this.InnerNativeSymbolSetHandle);
        else
            symbol = zbar_symbol_set_first_unfiltered(this.InnerNativeSymbolSetHandle);

        while ( symbol != IntPtr.Zero )
        {
            yield return new ZBarSymbol(symbol,0);
            symbol = zbar_symbol_next(symbol);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator ()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private extern static IntPtr zbar_symbol_next(IntPtr zBarSymbol); 

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private extern static IntPtr zbar_symbol_set_first_symbol(IntPtr zbarSymbolSet); 

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private extern static IntPtr zbar_symbol_set_first_unfiltered(IntPtr zbarSymbolSet);
}
```

The `InnerNativeSymbolSetHandle` used above to pass into the C functions was a property I bound on the ZBarSymbolSet class as luckily the ZBar iPhone SDK authors exposed pointers to the underlying structs from the C ZBar library:

```
// @interface ZBarSymbolSet : NSObject <NSFastEnumeration>
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface ZBarSymbolSet
{
    // @property (readonly, nonatomic) int count;
    [Export("count")]
    int Count { get; }

    // @property (readonly, nonatomic) const zbar_symbol_set_t *zbarSymbolSet;
    [Export("zbarSymbolSet")]
    IntPtr InnerNativeSymbolSetHandle{ get; }

    // @property (nonatomic) BOOL filterSymbols;
    [Export("filterSymbols")]
    bool FilterEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

So this is the manual solution.
I am still hoping there is an automatic way for btouch to do this (obviously not via these C functions, but via hooking into the `countByEnumeratingWithState` function of the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol. If objective-c can do it in a generic fashion using the objective-c for loop, then surely MonoTouch can automatically hook into it as well?

Comment: I've filed an enhancement bug about this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4391

Comment: Any chance you could share your binding and a sample project?

Comment: @Rick Already have. http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3515884&group_id=189236&atid=928517 
Doesn't include a sample project but it is a very thin wrapper around the Obj-C library, so just follow the existing ZBar iOS SDK sample project: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi, @tyson. I am binding Brighcove SDK to xamarin but stuck at NSFastEnumeration used in iOS SDK. I dint find any alternative. after googling for 2-3 days only found your answer as accepted and I am sharing my binding code https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32833995/BrightcovePlayersdkBinding-21apr.zip  if you can help me to generate dll through this.