# Xamarin binding objective-c BrightCove IOS SDK

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind the BrightCove IOS SDK v4.3.5 but i'm stuck with the following error :
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NSFastEnumeration' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)

And also there is a problem with INSFastEnumeration which is not defined

I'am using Xamarin IOS Sharpie 2.1.6

There is an open bug regarding this:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4391

Could someone please help me regarding this issue ? / did someone make a binding project to a recent brightcove ios sdk ?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like someone posted a manual solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057343/binding-an-obj-c-type-implementing-the-nsfastenumeration-protocol-to-monotouch